# Zero assignement in inline comparison

Tags: python

Example:

```
>>> x = 10
>>> x = x > 9 and 0 or x
>>> x
10
```

while:

```
>>> x = 10
>>> x = x > 9 and 1 or x
>>> x
1
```

Obviously 0 is treated as boolean False. How to use inline comparison to assign integer 0?

Comment: Can you specify which result you want?

Comment: I want 0 if number is greater then 9

Comment: What do you want if it is not greater than 9?

Comment: I want `x` if not greater then 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want this

```
 x= 0 if x > 9 else x
```

This is the python way of traditional ternary operators in c like languages.

The code snippet that you have will always give x or 1 for x > 9:

```
x = x > 9 and 0 or x
```

This is interpreted as

```
x = (x > 9 and 0) or x
x = 0 or x
x =  x
```

The other version

```
x = x > 9 and 1 or x
```

is interpreted as

```
x = (x > 9 and 1) or x
x = 1 or x # or gets short-circuited so second expression is not evaluated
x = 1
```

Comment: For fun this also seem to work fine: `x = int(x > 9 and '0' or x)`, although is worse solution of course

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
x = 0 if x > 9 else x
```